# Can I use OpenCL with Monogame?

Tags: opengl-es, opencl, opentk, monogame, cloo

I'm looking at Monogame for developing with. The site mentions it has OpenTK "under the hood". Does this mean I could have solid access to OpenCL using Monogame, or has OpenCL been split off into Cloo? My primary objectives are cross-platform, high-performance OpenGL ES & OpenCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, my understanding is that Cloo is a .NET wrapper for OpenCL, so if you are doing MonoGame development, I would think you would use Cloo which should give you access to everything you need in OpenCL. Looking through the source code a bit, I noticed XNA libraries are used a lot. As far as OpenTK goes, I mostly noticed the use of it for audio in linux and MacOS. Also it makes use of the Tao.SDL wrapper. To answer your question, afik, yes you can use OpenCL in MonoGame, and yes I think this will do very  nicely for your purposes. CHEERS